# git pull removed my local changed files without conflicts

Tags: git, pull

actually I am asking if git pull delete local commited changes when the same files in remote repository has been removed by the latest other user's commit ?

Comment: If your branching workflow is such that Git views the deletion of the files as being the more recent change, then yes, doing a pull can remove files.

Comment: In fact, one of my colleagues has deleted some files in the remote branch, when the other one commited his changed files in local and tried to push git asked him pull the remote changes before pushing so when he wrote git pull the local files removed without any conflict so I need to know if this can happen . Thank you any way @Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `git pull` will remove files that have been deleted in another repository. So backup the files before pulling.

Save them for longer period if you think you need them. Because `git checkout` will also remove the files if you switch to a branch where these files were removed.